# Numpy is installed, but astropy says numpy is not installed

Tags: python, windows, numpy, conda, choco

An ImportError is thrown when my program searches for Numpy. Yet, numpy is installed as seen by the `import numpy` working properly.
[image]

I've tried

- uninstalling python and numpy and reinstalling with choco
- with pip
- and with conda.

None seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

Does `import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)` work when you execute c:\agent03_work\s\turo.venv\bin\python.exe ? If not, you need to `c:\agent03\_work\s\turo\.venv\bin\pip install numpy` and you should be sorted.